How can i create app service in Azure with the same name as another?
I have an app service called TestApp that resides in Central US in a ResourceGroup called TestGroup.
I want to create an app service with the same name in a different resourcegroup and region .
How can i do this ?
These are the steps i took.

Created a new resourcegroup (TestGroup2)
Tried to create the app in the RG TestGroup2 with a different region of North Central US .

The issue is , it still says that "the app name cannot be used" .
How can i create an app with the same name as another in Azure ?

No, web site(app service) name must be unique globally.

For details, docs
